# How to filter last item of child collection?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm trying to query all posts that have it's last comment created today  || haven't yet had comment. How can I make that kind query filter in Django?

Here are my Models

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()


class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Q` to filter on `Post` objects with comments which were added today or which have no comments.

```py
from datetime import date
from django.db.models import Q

Post.objects.filter(Q(comments__created_at__gte=date.today()) | Q(comments__isnull=True))
```

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks Mickey, you saved my day.